# How we can change colour when refreshing and turns again to original colour within 2 - 4 seconds?

Tags: c#, asp.net

For eg..in Stackoverflow site, after giving answer, if we are refreshing the page, it displays the answer with orange color and turns to white beautifully?

How we have to do this ? Can it is possible in asp.net - C# ? .. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but a quick look at the source for the page shows that StackOverflow is using JQuery, so it might be using this feature;

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Fade